# The Behaviour Of Goroutines with Channels

Tags: go, goroutine, channel

The output of the code given bellow and is somewhat confusing, Please help me understand the behaviour of the channels and goroutines and how 
does the execution actually takes place.

I have tried to understand the flow of the program but the statement after the "call of goroutine" gets executed, even though the goroutine is called,
later on the statements in goroutines are executed,

on second "call of goroutine" the behaviour is different and the sequence of printing/flow of program changes.

Following is the code:

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func main() {
        fmt.Println("1")
        done := make(chan string)
        go test(done)
        fmt.Println("7")
        fmt.Println(<-done)
        fmt.Println("8")
        fmt.Println(<-done)
        fmt.Println("9")
        fmt.Println(<-done)
    }
    func test(done chan string) {
        fmt.Println("2")
        done <- "3"
        done <- "10"
        fmt.Println("4")
        done <- "5"
       fmt.Println("6")
    }
```

The result of the above code:

```
1
7
2
3
8
10
9
4
6
5
```

Please help me understand why and how this result comes out.

Comment: If you keep running it (not in playground) you'll likely get different results each time. Concurrency is non-deterministic and any expectations you have about the order of non-locking operations is wrong. You have to think about program flow differently when looking at concurrent code; it is not a single, predictable flow, but multiple concurrent *independent* flows. It's only at the locking points (eg channel send/receive) where they impact one another.

Comment: I have ran this code in VSCode but the output is same every time and the sequence doesn't change.

I know somewhat how concurrency works, but this program is always giving the exact same output in VSCode, why is that so???

Comment: Because that's the way it runs it. The order here isn't completely guaranteed, but there's also not enough variation to get different output when running under the same conditions.

Comment: Which part of the output is confusing. And what value would you expect? I would recomend that you start with a shorter example.

Comment: When I run a program containing goroutines, I know that in case of goroutines the output will always be in different order and no particular order is guaranteed, but i ran this program in **VSCode** it gives the same output every time i ran it, no matter how many times.

One more thing, why does the program print out the statement just after the call is given to the goroutine, .i.e why is it printing out `7 `, even though the 
`go test (done)` func/goroutine is called, why doesn't it print out `2` as the func/goroutine is called and the control is with the `go test(done){}` function???

Answer (score 4):

### Concept 1: [Channels](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2)

Visualize a channel as a tube where data goes in one end and out the other.  The first data in is the first data that comes out the other side.  There are buffered channels and non-buffered channels but for your example you only need to understand the default channel, which is unbuffered.  Unbuffered channels only allow one value in the channel at a time.

#### Writing to an Unbuffered Channel

Code that looks like this writes data into one end of the channel.

```
ch <- value
```

Now, this code actually *waits* to be done executing until something reads the value out of the channel.  An unbuffered channel only allows for one value at a time to be within it, and doesn't continue executing until it is read.  We'll see later how this affects the ordering of how your code is executed.

#### Reading from an Unbuffered Channel

To read from an unbuffered channel (visualize taking a value out of the channel), the code to do this looks like

```
[value :=] <-ch
```

> when you read code documentation [things in] square brackets indicate that what's within them is optional.  Above, without the [value :=] you'll just take a value out of the channel and don't use it for anything.

Now when there's a value in the channel, this code has two side effects.  One, it reads the value out of a channel in whatever routine we are in now, and proceeds with the value.  The *other* effect it has is to **allow the goroutine which put the value into the channel to continue**.  This is the critical bit that's necessary to understand your example program.

In the event there is NO value in the channel yet, it will **wait for a value to be written into the channel before continuing**.  In other words, the thread blocks until the channel has a value to read.

### Concept 2: [Goroutines](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1)

A goroutine allows your code to continue executing two pieces of code *concurrently*.  This can be used to allow your code to execute faster, or attend to multiple problems at the same time (think of a server where multiple users are loading pages from it at the same time).

Your question arises when you try to figure out the ordering that code is executed when you have multiple routines executing concurrently.  This is a good question and others have correctly stated that *it depends*.  When you spawn two goroutines, the ordering of which lines of code are executed is arbitrary.

The code below with a goroutine may print `executing a()` or `end main()` first.  This is due to the fact that spawning a gorouting means there are two concurrent streams (threads) of execution happening at the same time.  In this case, one thread stays in `main()` and the other starts executing the first line in `a()`.  How the runtime decides to choose which to run first is arbitrary.

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("start main()")
    go a()
    fmt.Println("end main()")
}

func a() {
    fmt.Println("executing a()")
}
```

#### Goroutines + Channels

Now let's use a channel to control the ordering of what get's executed, when.
The only difference now is we create a channel, pass it into the goroutine, and wait for it's value to be written before continuing in main.  From earlier, we discussed how the routine reading the value from a channel needs to wait until there's a value in the channel before continuing.  Since `executing a()` is always printed before the channel is written to, we will always wait to read the value put into the channel until `executing a()` has printed.  Since we read from the channel (which happens after the channel is written) before printing `end main()`, `executing a()` will always print before `end main()`. I made [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rn_ZmDWJfQT) so you can run it for yourself.

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("start main()")
    ch := make(chan int)
    go a(ch)
    <-ch
    fmt.Println("end main()")
}

func a(ch chan int) {
    fmt.Println("executing a()")
    ch <- 0
}
```

### Your Example

I think at this point you could figure out what happens when, and what might happen in a different order.  My own first attempt was wrong when I went through it in my head (see edit history).  You have to be careful!  I'll not give the right answer, upon editing, since I realized this may be a homework assignment.

**EDIT:** more semantics about `<-done`

On my first go through, I forgot to mention that `fmt.Println(<-done)` is conceptually the same as the following.

```
value := <-done
fmt.Println(value)
```

This is important because it helps you see that when the `main()` thread reads from the `done` channel, it doesn't print it at the same time.  These are two separate steps to the runtime.

Comment: Just upvoted - and wanted to say, this is simply the best answer I have read on Goroutines channels!